# Чтение файла в переносимой библиотеки C# (Portable Class Library)

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать в переносимой библиотеки чтение файла? Возможно я что-то делаю не так, но в переносимой библиотеке не доступны такие класс как **File**, **FileStream**, невозможно создать экземпляр класса **StreamReader** или **TextReader** с помощью конструктора, которому передается в качестве параметра путь к файлу.
При попытке написать вот такой код, ругается, что 'не удается преобразовать из "string" в "System.IO.Stream"'.

```
using System.IO;
namespace Project
{
   class Class1
   {
      public Class1(string path)
      {
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "...но в переносимой библиотеке не доступны такие класс как File.." - да, Вы что-то делаете не так. Это максимум, что можно сказать, прочитав Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73077/discussion-on-question-by-oleg-klezovich------c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, среди списка платформ вы выбрали в том числе Silverlight или что-то подобное. Silverlight - это плагин к браузеру, и ему запрещен доступ к локальным файлам; потому там и нет нужных вам классов.

В таком виде проблема решения не имеет; вам нужно выбирать одно из двух: или доступ к файлам, или экзотические платформы.

Comment: Как вы правильно указали, используется именно Portable Class Library. Только не для Silverlight, а для iOS и Android. Думал потом попробовать написать приложение на андроид с использованием этой библиотеки, дабы не переписывать код дважды. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае лучшим выходом из ситуации является использовать в качестве параметра не строку с адресом на файл, а непосредственно **StreamReader**, и просто открывать файл в конечном коде и передавать полученный стрим в конструктор?

Comment: @OlegKlezovich видимо, да. Принимать TextReader или Stream Это при условии что вы вообще сможете открыть там файл.

Comment: под Android никогда не писал программы. Там могут возникнуть проблемы с открытием файла?

Comment: @OlegKlezovich если там и правда нет System.IO.File - то да, могут...

Comment: Под UWP есть, например, StorageFile, который невозможно сконструировать по произвольному пути.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем консольное приложение

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 cl = new Class1("d://test.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляем в "солютион" средствами VisualStudio новый проект - отдельный класс `Class1` в виде dll.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
      public Class1(string path)
      {
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
         string str = reader.ReadLine();
      }
    }
}
```

В менеджере проектов на у консольного проекта в разделе References добавляем ссылку на проект Class1

Компилируем solution, запускаем в отладчике - все работает

Comment: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, прежде чем публиковать ответ, я всегда проверяю его работоспособность. В моем окружении Ms VisualStudio 2012 FrameWork 4 все работает

Comment: А вы не забыли что у автора Portable Class Library, а не FrameWork 4?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, там написано "...в переносимой библиотеки...", которые можно интерпретировать, как желание автора создать отдельную переносимую dll. Там нет слов "Portable Class Library" :)

Comment: Учите английский (и официальную локализацию Visual Studio надмозгами). Portable Class Library по-русски называется именно как "переносимая библиотека".

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov  - "...Учите английский..." - no comment, а может все же автору вопросу, до его публикации, все же следует думать, все ли в нем описано, дабы не заставлять людей зря тратить бесценное время?

Comment: А чего именно там не было написано?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73074/discussion-between---and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо будет в PLC проект добавить интерфейс.

Пример интерфейса:

```
public interface IFileWorker
{
    Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string filename); // проверка существования файла
    Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text);   // сохранение текста в файл
    Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename);  // загрузка текста из файла
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFilesAsync();  // получение файлов из определнного каталога
    Task DeleteAsync(string filename);  // удаление файла
}
```

Далее для каждого из проектов (Android, iOS и т.д.) реализовать данный интерфейс.

Пример реализации для Andriod:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileApp.Droid.FileWorker))]
namespace FileApp.Droid
{
    public class FileWorker : IFileWorker
    {
        public Task DeleteAsync(string filename)
        {
            // удаляем файл
            File.Delete(GetFilePath(filename));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string filename)
        {
            // получаем путь к файлу
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            // существует ли файл
            bool exists = File.Exists(filepath);
            return Task<bool>.FromResult(exists);
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFilesAsync()
        {
            // получаем все все файлы из папки
            IEnumerable<string> filenames = from filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(GetDocsPath())
                                            select Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            return Task<IEnumerable<string>>.FromResult(filenames);
        }

        public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(text);
            }
        }
        // вспомогательный метод для построения пути к файлу
        string GetFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(GetDocsPath(), filename);
        }
        // получаем путь к папке MyDocuments
        string GetDocsPath()
        {
            return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        }
    }
}
```

Для iOS проекта:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileApp.iOS.FileWorker))]
namespace FileApp.iOS
{
    public class FileWorker : IFileWorker
    {
        public Task DeleteAsync(string filename)
        {
            File.Delete(GetFilePath(filename));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string filename)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            bool exists = File.Exists(filepath);
            return Task<bool>.FromResult(exists);
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFilesAsync()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> filenames = from filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(GetDocsPath())
                                            select Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            return Task<IEnumerable<string>>.FromResult(filenames);
        }

        public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(text);
            }
        }

        string GetFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(GetDocsPath(), filename);
        }
        string GetDocsPath()
        {
            return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        }
    }
}
```

Для вызова методов, определенных в интерфейсе, используется [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Например, чтобы прочитать из файла, в PLC проект достаточно добавить следующую строчку кода:

```
    string Text = await DependencyService.Get<IFileWorker>().LoadTextAsync("Example.txt");
```

Материал взят от [сюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/6.1.php)