# Как вызвать функцию, определённую в Xamarin.Droid, в проекте Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin

Есть Shared Project решение.

Как из главного проекта вызвать функцию, определённую в проекте для Android?

Например, функцию, запускающую фоновую задачу.

Comment: Посмотрите данный пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784872/264267

Comment: Спасибо, @Emigrant. Полезная ссылка. Воспользовался DependencyService.